# Calling python script from VBA

Tags: python, vba

There seems to be a lot of threads on this one and they all point to this solution:

```
Function call_py()

Dim rv As Variant
Const pypath = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "
Const scriptpath = "c:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py"

    rv = Shell(pypath & scriptpath, vbNormalFocus)


End Function
```

or something similar.  All this does though is make a shell pop up and disappear without executing the script.  What am I doing wrong?

P.

Comment: If I were you, I would write those commands in a batch file, and then run the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub bat()
Dim batch, fso As Object
Dim path As String
path = "c:\Users\user\Desktop\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set batch = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "python.bat", True)
batch.writeline "cd " & path
batch.writeline "python test.py"
batch.Close

Shell path & "python.bat", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome Tehscript!! I've been looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the argument "-i" to inspect the execution.

The console will remain opened and you'll be able to see why it's not working as expected :

```
Shell "python -i " & scriptpath
```

And make sure that the paths are quoted if they contain a space character.

Comment: Ha ha! This was going to be my next question!  Thanks.